# Two inputs not submitting both values on form React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

When I click submit on the button, only 1 value is submitted to the object instead of both. I have worked out that the state is updated correctly until the submit button is pressed and only 1 value is submitted into the obj.

I have used the functions as below:

```
  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: {term1: event.target.value }});
  }

  onChange2 = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: {term2: event.target.value }});
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let obj = {
        result1: this.state.term.term1,
        result2: this.state.term.term2,     
    };
    {console.log('obj', obj)}
    this.setState({
        term: {
            term1: '',
            term2: ''
        },
        items: [...this.state.items, obj]
    });
  }
```

I have used the render as below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.term.term1} onChange={this.onChange} />
          <input value={this.state.term.term2} onChange={this.onChange2} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <List items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My state structure is as follows:

```
this.state = {
  term: {
    term1: '',
    term2: ''
  },
  items: []
};
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I have just edited this in the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're mutating the term state. You need to update the state like:

```
onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ term: {...this.state.term, term1: event.target.value }});
}
```

Do the similar approach with onChange2. And then you'll get the merged term: term1 and term2.

You may even use [updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) callback like this:

```
onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
     term: {
       ...prevState.term,
       term1: event.target.value
     }
  }))
 }
```

---

You may even just define single handler for both changes as commented by [Henok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8443899/henok-tesfaye):

```
onChange = (event, termNum) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
     term: {
       ...prevState.term,
       [termNum]: event.target.value
     }
  }))
 }
```

And pass the termNum with responding term1, or term2 in your onChange:

```
onChange={this.onChange(term1)}
// there are sorts of methods to pass the parameter.
```

You may check my another post for further details about [using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863128/2138752).

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a treat! 
For my understanding, why do you need to add the ...this.state.term?

Comment: Without the spread operator (...) you are simply replacing the term object each time onChange is called so  `term: {term1: 'something'}` becomes `term: {term2: 'something else'}`

Comment: And instead of using two methods , onChange & onChange 2 you can use computed property. onChange = (event, termNum) => {
  this.setState({ term: {...this.state.term, [termNum]: event.target.value }});
}

Answer (score 0):

Try below change

```
 onChange = (event) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         term: {
            ...prevState.term,
           term1: event.target.value
         }
      }))
 }

 onChange2 = (event) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
         term: {
            ...prevState.term,
           term2: event.target.value
         }
     }))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your state is overwriting itself each time your onChange functions are called. If you use the spread operator you'll keep your current values of state without over writing it.

```
onChange2 = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      term: {
        ...this.state.term,
        term2: event.target.value 
      }
    })
  }
```

Do the same for the other onChange even you have as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It works and is appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
onSubmit = (value1, value2) = ev => {
   ev.preventDefault();
   console.log(value1,value2)
 }
```

and call like this

```
 <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit(this.state.term.term1,this.state.term.term2)}>
```