# Call function on click of link in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react  property instead of  tag. So what i need to do is to call a function on click of link.What approach should i need to follow to achieve this.can i use the below function.

```
<Link to={`/testimonial/${post.id}`} className="red">
  <span onClick={this.saveData(post.title)}>More</span>
</Link>
```

I have to trigger the function, that will save data to localStorage and then redirect user to the component.

Thanks.

Comment: Value of onClick is incorrect. You must define it like this: `onClick={() => this.saveData(post.title)}`

Comment: thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. You can use event handlers in `<Link />`. Or, you may even bind the event handler in the child or parent element if you want to have more control. Both are successive:

```
<Link to={`/component/${post.id}`}/>
  <span onClick={this.saveDataToLocalStorage}>More</span>
</Link>
```

Alternaively, you may avoid using `<Link />` and use normal element as you want:

```
<span onClick={this.saveDataToLocalStorage(post.id)}>More</span>
```

And inside the function, you may redirect to the path:

```
saveDataToLocalStorage(postId) {
this.props.history.push(`/component/${postId}`)
```

This way, you'll have more control, you can log, alert etc. and when you wish redirect to the page.

Comment: Hi, I tried it works. But thanks for your answer. But please tell me, how can i redirect user after my function work done to the same url?

Comment: your code is not working. I applied alert in the given function and the alert is showing without clicking on link.

Comment: I am saying, the function is calling without click on link. alert is showing when i refresh page where link to next page exists.

Comment: You mean, I need to put "More" Link text in span?

Comment: Not working. alert is again calling at render. I updated my answer. You can see that what i am using.

Comment: No, on same page. where i have links to redirect to another page.

Comment: alert is again calling on render, without clicking on link.

Comment: I bind it in constructor like this: this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this)

so why i need to bind it again?

Comment: then there might another  issue. it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788613/react-js-the-most-efficient-way-to-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-without/52788901#52788901