# why is my bind not working in constructor

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a very simple two button state. where if i click abutton, A component displays and if bbutton is clicked then component B. I'm mapping through array of items so that each of them have their own buttons state. Lets say if I click item 1's button B then I want only first Item B to show. Right now All of them gets triggered at once.  I have bounded each of them in the constructor but still i'm unable to get only the once the once clicked to trigger and show the relevant component.

```
class Home extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lists: []
      showA: true,
      showB: false
    }
    this.aButtonHandler = this.aButtonHandler.bind(this);
    this.bButtonHandler = this.bButtonHandler.bind(this);
  }



  aButtonHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      showA: true,
      showB: false 
    })
  }



  bButtonHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      showA: false,
      showB: true
    })
  }




 render(){
    return (
      <div> 

       {this.state.lists.map(detail => 
        <li>{detail.id}</li>
        <button onClick={(e) => this.aButtonHandler(e)} >see A</button>
        <button onClick={(e) => this.bButtonHandler(e)} >see B</button> 

        {this.state.showA ? 
          <ComponentA />  : null
        }

        {this.state.showB ? 
           <ComponentB />  : null
         }
       )}

       </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Read thoroughly, you will be able to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788613/react-js-the-most-efficient-way-to-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-without/52788901#52788901

Answer (score 1):

If you are using arrow functions no need to bind functions.

If you want to bind then change it to normal function like this.

```
aButtonHandler(e){...}
bButtonHandler(e){...}
```

Comment: I changed to normal function. But It is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bind in constructor no need to use arrow function, just use regular functions and pass the function directly to onClick

```
aButtonHandler(e) { this.setState({ showA: true, showB: false }); }

bButtonHandler(e) { this.setState({ showA: false, showB: true }); }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.lists.map(detail => (
        <div>
          <li>{detail.id}</li>
          <button onClick={this.aButtonHandler}>see A</button>
          <button onClick={this.bButtonHandler}>see B</button>
          {this.state.showA ? <ComponentA /> : null}
          {this.state.showA ? <ComponentB /> : null}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar thread has all the detailed information.. definitely a good read to solve on your own. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788613/react-js-the-most-efficient-way-to-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-without/52788901#52788901