# Rotate image with respect to arrow key react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js. I am trying to rotate an image by clicking an arrow key.
Someone help me out and also share some documentation for learning react js.

Thanks in advance.

**My code**

**.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Ballimg from '../Image/ImageMovement.gif'
import Style from '../Style/ImageComponentStyle.module.css'

class Ball extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            imageDirection: Style.right
        };
    }
    handleKeyDown(e){
        if(e.KeyCode === 37){
            this.setState({imageDirection : Style.left})
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode === 38){
            this.setState({imageDirection : Style.up})
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode === 39){
            this.setState({imageDirection : Style.right})
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode === 40){
            this.setState({imageDirection : Style.down})
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={Ballimg} alt="ball movement" className={this.state.imageDirection} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}/>
            </div>
        );   
    }
}
export default Ball;
```

**.module.css**

```
.down {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.left {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.up {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.right{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo:

```
// Not e.KeyCode
e.keyCode === 37
```

Then, you might want to set a global listener for `keyDown` or the event will only work when the element is focused:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => { 
  //e.keyCode
});
```

Full hooks example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        setDirection(180);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        setDirection(-90);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        setDirection(0);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        setDirection(90);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <img
      style={{ transform: `rotate(${direction}deg)` }}
      alt="cat"
      src={image}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-60901940-KeyDownExample]

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not used public class method, you can call the method just like this:

```
onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
```

The method binding with `this` is required to bind `this`. So, if you use `onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}`, you have to bind like:

```
this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this) // inside constructor
```

Or, using public class method:

```
handleKeyDown = (e) => {}
```

For more details, I suggest you to read my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788901/2138752).

Comment: How it is related to the question?