# What's the difference between the two ReactJS click function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**1st type**

```
      {this.state.persons.map((person,index) => {
        return (
          <Person
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            click={()=>this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
          ></Person>
        )
      })}
```

**2nd type**

```
      {this.state.persons.map(person => {
        return (
          <Person
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            click={deletePersonHandler(index)}
          ></Person>
        )
      })}
```

The code above should delete the specific person from the state, but why is the 2nd type not working, i need to know the difference between the two function calls.

Comment: Read thoroughly, you'll understand :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788901/2138752

Comment: Problem in 'index'. Code in map use it, but second havent him.